# Iterated crossproducts

Tags: linear-algebra, mg.metric-geometry

Let $S_0$ be a set of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Now iteratively define $S_{j+1}$ by taking all possible crossproducts of vectors in $S_j$ and normalizing such that the vector of maximum norm has unit norm. That is
\begin{equation}
S'_{j+1} = \{ v_1 \times \cdots \times v_{n-1} :  v_1, \dots, v_{n-1}  \in S_{j},  \} 
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
S_{j+1} = \{ m^{-1} w : w \in S_{j+1}' \}
\end{equation}
where $m = \sup \{ ||w|| : w \in S_{j+1}' \}$.

Clearly, there are some finite configurations that are fixed points such as $S_0 = \{e_1, \dots, e_n \}$. Also taking $S_0$ to be the vectors comprising a ball of radius $1$ yields a fixed point.

My question: Do we know anything about what happens when $j$ gets sufficiently large for **general/generic configurations**? Do we know anything about convergence or convergence to a finite loop? Has this question been studied before?